# Diffuse BSDF get reflection from texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I'm using Cycles Render. I have plane with an image texture.
(first picture)
And I have object with just a diffuse BSDF
(Second picture)
So why is the object with the diffuse BSDF is not white?
(third picture)

[image: cycles nodes]

[image: diffuse BSDF]

[image: rendered result]

Comment: Did you hear of bounce light ? White light at first bounce is getting the color of the ground material and give this color to the second bounce.

Comment: This is how light works in real-life. If you don't want this to happen, set the number of diffuse bounces to 0 in *Properties > Render > Light Paths*